# Como eu represento um looping no diagrama de casos de uso?

Tags: casos-de-uso

Meu projeto precisa que um looping aconteça, onde basicamente quatro casos de uso se conectam e repetem até um determinado número X de vezes. Quando atinge esse valor o looping deve ser quebrado chamando outro caso de uso.

[Imagem do Caso de Uso de Exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ac5X.png)

No exemplo acima eu conectei os quatro casos de uso como include, com exceção do último, que se liga com o final e com o início através de um extend, para deteminar que uma das duas opções será chamada dependendo do valor de repetições. Isso está correto? Ou preciso representar um looping de uma forma diferente?

Comment: não se representa loop um caso de uso, um loop seria uma impletação de código e o caso de uso tem de ser agnóstico à implementação, pode adicionar um label informando "deve ser repetido 3x", ou ainda no descritivo do caso de uso, não no diagrama

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.